# Jquery UI autocomplete not displaying well on Twitter Bootstrap based website

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, autocomplete

So Im using Bootstrap 3, JQuery and Jquery-UIs autocomplete. So on the my project, the result looks like this,

[image]

But according to the documentation page, it is supposed to look like this

[image]

with the clickable items on mouse over and everything. My search box HTML is as follows:

```
<form role="search" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="titles" type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">GO</button>
        </form>
```

The documentation page for jquery-ui autocomplete widget is [here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default)

Any pointers? Thanks in advance. PS:The photos were taken by a potato :-)

Comment: Bootstrap 3 is replacing the default style. Try this https://gist.github.com/daz/2168334

Comment: tried it but it did not completely solve the problem

Comment: Do you have this in a place that is publicly accessible so we could inspect it?

Comment: @SethMcClaine, I already answered it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dmlittle gave me the idea

You need to also style the autocomplete widget the Boostrap way

```
.ui-autocomplete {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1000;
cursor: default;
padding: 0;
margin-top: 2px;
list-style: none;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #ccc
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 }
  .ui-autocomplete > li {
padding: 3px 20px;
     }
   .ui-autocomplete > li.ui-state-focus {
  background-color: #DDD;
    }
 .ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
  display: none;
 }
```